# subsubsubsection and revtex 4.1

Tags: revtex

Is there a way to use subsubsubsection in `\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}`?

For `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`, by adding the following comments
I am able to use subsubsubsection. (These comments are taken from this web site)
But it is not working for revtex4-1.

```
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

Comment: Welcome! It would be great if you could specify what `this page` means, i.e. set the appropriate hyperlink.

Comment: Could you please edit your question such that it provides a minimal working example (MWE), which begins with `\documentclass[...]{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`. Please use an indent of four characters for a code block.

Comment: you can use the standard latex command for section headings at this level, which is `\paragraph` there is no need to define a new command.

Comment: \documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}
         \begin{document}
               \tableofcontents{}
            \section{Introduction}
                   \subsection{Subsection}
                 \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
                        \paragraph{Subsubsubsection}
          \end{document}  If I use this code block, section number for the paragraph is not appeared in the table of contents. But I want it to be appeared. (sorry for my unappropriate writing)